# jQuery: change function not being induced?

Tags: jquery

i have the following jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.restrictiveOptions input[type!=checkbox], .restrictiveOptions select').change(function() {
                // check off enabled for that row if anything changed
                $(this).closest('.fieldRow').find('.restrictiveOptionEnabled').attr('checked','true');
                alert('changed');
            });
        });
```

however, when i change the inputs or selects, nothing happens (not even the alert)!

i have checked that `$('.restrictiveOptions input[type!=checkbox], .restrictiveOptions select')` is correct (by using firebug console and checking the .length, which returned 484).
i have also made sure there are no syntax errors.

what do you think i'm doing wrong? thanks!

EDIT: i've updated the code and changed `$(self)` to `$(this)`, but am still not seeing an alert. here is sample html (sorry for the formatting, i added line breaks but it is generated by php):

```
<fieldset class="restrictiveOptions"><legend class="collapsable">
<img width="12" height="12" title="Collapse" alt="Collapse" class="toggle" src="branding/default/images/collapse.gif"> Restrictive Options</legend>
<div style="">
<div class="fieldRow">
<div class="label">
<label>Executive</label></div>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
<div class="cellValue">
<select onchange="changeRestrictionValue(&quot;event42_41&quot;)" id="event42_41_restrictionType" name="event42_41_restrictionType">
<option selected="selected" value="1">is equal to</option>
<option value="2">is not equal to</option></select> 
<span id="event42_41_restrictionValue1Wrapper" class="event42_41_restrictionValueWrapper">
<select onchange="validateField(this)" name="event42_41_restrictionValue" id="event42_41_restrictionValue">
<option value="76">Yes</option>
<option value="77">No</option></select></span>
<span style="display: none;" id="event42_41_restrictionValue2Wrapper" class="event42_41_restrictionValueWrapper">
<select onchange="validateField(this)" name="event42_41_restrictionValue1" id="event42_41_restrictionValue1">
<option value="76">Yes</option>
<option value="77">No</option></select> and 
<select onchange="validateField(this)" name="event42_41_restrictionValue2" id="event42_41_restrictionValue2">
<option value="76">Yes</option>
<option value="77">No</option></select></span></div>
<div style="float: right;" class="cellValue">
<label for="event42_41_enabled">Enabled?</label>
<input type="checkbox" style="vertical-align: sub; margin: 2px; padding: 0pt;" class="restrictiveOptionEnabled" title="Check me to enable this restrictive option" name="event42_41_enabled" id="event42_41_enabled" value="">
</div></div></div>
```

Comment: Could you post your accompanying html?

Comment: Four hundred and eighty-four!!!!

Comment: @HurnsMobile: i did, but its solved. thanks anyways!
@Pointy: its a beast of a form =) dynamically created code blocks, and each one has this code in it (i'm actually only showing one row in the sample html where there will probably be at least 10)
actually, lets do this math
each row has 4 selects/inputs, each block has 11 rows (in my test code, but the number of rows is dynamic as well), and there are currently 11 blocks. 11*11 = 121, 121 * 4 = 484 =)

Comment: I think the "dynamically-created code blocks" part is what the problem was, and that's why using "live" works.  If things in the form change, then those event handler assignments are lost. What "live" does is rely on event bubbling, and it performs that selector match on the target of every "change" event that happens on the page. Thus no matter when your elements arrive in the form, that handler will apply to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shouldn't make any difference *unless* there's something going on that you haven't mentioned. Instead of directly binding the handler to all those elements, try setting up a "live" handler:

```
$(function() {
  $('.restrictiveOptions input[type!=checkbox], .restrictiveOptions select')
    .live('click', function(ev) {
      $(this).closest('.fieldRow').find('.restrictiveOptionEnabled').attr('checked','true');
      alert('changed');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `self`, you need `this`, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.restrictiveOptions input[type!=checkbox], .restrictiveOptions select').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('.fieldRow').find('.restrictiveOptionEnabled').attr('checked', true);
    alert('changed');
  });
});
```

Inside an event handler like this, `this` refers to the element in question, `self` is often used to hang onto a reference of some sort, but it's not inherently available, it's something you need to define.  In this case, it's trying to do `$(undefined)`, which isn't *exactly* what you want :)

Comment: i've made that change, but the alert is still not showing up =(

Comment: @Garrett - Are you seeing any errors in your console? I updated for the more accurate `.attr('checked', true);`, but seems you're still getting an error.  Here's a working version against your markup: http://jsfiddle.net/UKnmx/ Something outside the question must be erroring?

Comment: it seems to have been the 'change' function, and switching it to 'live' made it work. OHHH i think its because i generated the rows on the document load as well, so that code must've ran first and not found the elements because they weren't generated yet.
thanks so much for your effort. it was my mistake.

Comment: @Garrett - Ah yes then @Pointy's solution will work...for future reference, things present in the initial document vs. generated later is a *huge* difference :)

Comment: i'm just starting to see that now; i tried adding a jquery datepicker to some inputs but only realized a while later that the reason it wasn't working was because the inputs were generated after the document load! i wish there was a way to use the 'live' function for any jquery function, like when the element loads, do this.

Comment: @Garrett - There is something for this, the `.livequery()` plugin:  http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery/